# Altium: What are these vertical yellow lines

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I was aligning 3D files in Altium and at some point I noticed these solid vertical lines had appeared. They seem to stretch from top to bottom of the entire document and I can't seem to remove them. I tried resetting Altium but that didn't work. How did I add these lines and how can I delete them?

[image: yellow vertical lines]

Comment: Could you zoom out a little more? It's difficult to tell based on the image provided. Not enough context

Comment: Those might be snap guide lines: http://wiki.altium.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21660272

Answer (score 1):

They are guides.

Go Tools/Grid Manager. Theres ahould be all those guides.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to just hide them temporarily?

Comment: Yes. You can hid them if you unclick the "enabled" option

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this, in the latest version of Altium this has been changed.

It is now in "Properties" > "Guide Manager"

In this section you can edit, place, hide, and remove these "Work Guides"